# SQL Left join where data missing in join column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm not even sure this is possible but I'm trying to join two tables together but I'm not getting my expected results. My query is as follows:

```
SELECT inc.NUMBER as TICKET,
inc.UNIV_NUM,
inc.ASSIGNEE,
work.SUBMIT_DATE
work.TYPE
FROM dbo.HELP_DESK as inc
LEFT JOIN dbo.WORKLOG as work on inc.NUMBER = work.NUMBER
Where inc.ASSIGNEE = 'AB049732'
and work.SUBMIT_DATE = (Select MAX(work2.SUBMIT_DATE) 
                        from dbo.WORKLOG as work2 
                        where work2.NUMBER = work.NUMBER
                        and work2.TYPE = '16000')
```

My tables look like this

inc

```
+---------+-----------+----------+
| NUMBER  | UNIV_NUM  | ASSIGNEE |
+---------+-----------+----------+
|  100001 |   4321781 | AB049732 |
|  100002 |   4232756 | AB049732 |
|  100003 |   4322534 | AB049732 |
|  100004 |   4328534 | AB049732 |
+---------+-----------+----------+
```

work

```
+--------+------------+-------+
| NUMBER |   DATE     | TYPE  |
+--------+------------+-------+
| 100001 | 23/05/2018 | 16000 |
| 100003 | 22/05/2018 | 16000 |
| 100004 | 22/05/2018 | 16000 |
+--------+------------+-------+
```

My expected output is:

```
+--------+----------+----------+------------+-------+
| NUMBER | UNIV_NUM | ASSIGNEE |    DATE    | TYPE  |
+--------+----------+----------+------------+-------+
| 100001 |  4321781 | AB049732 | 23/05/2018 | 16000 |
| 100002 |  4232756 | AB049732 | NULL       | NULL  |
| 100003 |  4322534 | AB049732 | 22/05/2018 | 16000 |
| 100004 |  4328534 | AB049732 | 22/05/2018 | 16000 |
+--------+----------+----------+------------+-------+
```

But my actual output is:

```
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+-------+
| NUMBER  | UNIV_NUM  | ASSIGNEE |   DATE     | TYPE  |
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+-------+
|  100001 |   4321781 | AB049732 | 23/05/2018 | 16000 |
|  100003 |   4322534 | AB049732 | 22/05/2018 | 16000 |
|  100004 |   4328534 | AB049732 | 22/05/2018 | 16000 |
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+-------+
```

Effectively, number 100002 isn't displaying despite being in the inc table. Am I doing something wrong or is this a case of you can't join to something that doesn't exist?

Comment: Move your WHERE condition that's filtering the work table as another condition in your LEFT JOIN.

Comment: This is because you have turned your left join into an inner join with your where predicate. Move that predicate to your join and it will return the data the way you want it.

Comment: your second where clause removes the row, move this to the on clause from the join and it will work again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your join condition is bad. Try this:

```
SELECT inc.NUMBER as TICKET,
inc.UNIV_NUM,
inc.ASSIGNEE,
work.SUBMIT_DATE
work.TYPE
FROM dbo.HELP_DESK as inc
LEFT JOIN dbo.WORKLOG as work on inc.NUMBER = work.NUMBER
and work.SUBMIT_DATE = (Select MAX(work2.SUBMIT_DATE) 
                        from dbo.WORKLOG as work2 
                        where work2.NUMBER = work.NUMBER
                        and work2.TYPE = '16000')
Where inc.ASSIGNEE = 'AB049732'
```

See the difference? If you put the `work.SUBMIT_DATE = ...` condition in the `Where` clause (as you did) then your join becomes an inner join. But you want an outer join.

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions!

```
SELECT h.NUMBER as TICKET, h.UNIV_NUM, h.ASSIGNEE,
       w.SUBMIT_DATE, w.TYPE
FROM dbo.HELP_DESK h LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT w.*, MAX(w2.SUBMIT_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY w.NUMBER) as max_submit_date
      FROM dbo.WORKLOG w
      WHERE w.TYPE = '16000'
     ) w
     ON h.NUMBER = w.NUMBER AND w.submit_date = w.max_submit_date
WHERE h.ASSIGNEE = 'AB049732';
```

This is subtly different from your query, but I think it is the logic you actually want.  Your query will find records that have the maximum submit date for type '16000' *regardless* of type.  I presume that you really want the types to align to the submit date.

If this interpretation is wrong, it is easy to adjust the query:

```
SELECT h.NUMBER as TICKET, h.UNIV_NUM, h.ASSIGNEE,
       w.SUBMIT_DATE, w.TYPE
FROM dbo.HELP_DESK h LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT w.*,
             MAX(CASE WHEN w.TYPE = '16000' THEN w2.SUBMIT_DATE END) OVER (PARTITION BY w.NUMBER) as max_submit_date
      FROM dbo.WORKLOG w
     ) w
     ON h.NUMBER = w.NUMBER AND w.submit_date = w.max_submit_date
WHERE h.ASSIGNEE = 'AB049732';
```

These versions are not only simpler, but they should have better performance as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE like this:

```
WITH WorkDates
    AS (SELECT SUBMIT_DATE,TYPE
        From WORKLOG work
        Where SUBMIT_DATE = (Select MAX(work2.SUBMIT_DATE) 
                        from dbo.WORKLOG as work2 
                        where work2.NUMBER = work.NUMBER
                        and work2.TYPE = '16000'))
SELECT inc.NUMBER as TICKET,
inc.UNIV_NUM,
inc.ASSIGNEE,
WorkDates.SUBMIT_DATE
WorkDates.TYPE
FROM dbo.HELP_DESK as inc
LEFT JOIN WorkDates on inc.NUMBER = WorkDates.NUMBER
Where inc.ASSIGNEE = 'AB049732'
```